# Unable to see color in vim after upgrade

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Recently updated the macOS to Bigsur and as part of the update, I also updated the packages through homebrew. My coc.nvim plugin was not working so, I reinstalled the package. And after that, I am unable to see the color of my scheme (gruvbox) which is also installed as a plugin. Now the screen is all grey with the dark background (the background was dark even previously). I am attaching the vim settings for clarification. The syntax setting is enabled and it is rightly picking erlang, the termguicolors is set as well. I am using mac terminal to invoke vim.

```
$ echo $TERM=xterm-256color
```

[image: vim settings screenshot]

I have not changed the .vimrc but here is the content:

```
set termguicolors
set tabstop=4
set number relativenumber
set guifont=Fira\ Code:h18
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set background=dark
call plug#begin()
Plug 'fatih/vim-go'
Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
Plug 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'nvie/vim-flake8'
Plug 'sirver/ultisnips'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'do': 'yarn install --frozen-lockfile'}
Plug 'vim-erlang/vim-erlang-runtime'
Plug 'rakesh-k/vim-antlr'
Plug 'vim-erlang/vim-erlang-runtime'
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim'
Plug 'vim-erlang/vim-erlang-runtime'
call plug#end()
colorscheme gruvbox
```

Comment: Not sure but try adding `syntax on` in ~/.vimrc

Comment: I have not changed the .vimrc. As I mentioned the colorscheme was working just fine before the updates (vim and OS). And I will appreciate if you can remove the downvote because it will hamper getting the correct response.

Comment: Terminal.app doesn't support so-called "true colors" so `set termguicolors` is bound to cause troubles. Either use a terminal emulator that supports that feature or use a colorscheme that doesn't require it.

Comment: @romainl removing the termguicolors from the .vimrc did the trick. Wonder how it worked earlier?

Comment: It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim colorschemes typically define styling attributes for basic terminals (`term`), color terminals (`cterm*`), and GUI (`gui*`). Here is an example:

```
highlight Comment ctermfg=240 guifg=#585858
```

that…

- uses color `240` from [the xterm palette](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) for foreground in color terminals,
- uses color `#585858` for foreground in GUI.

When you enable `&termguicolors`, you are telling Vim to use the GUI-specific value, broken into R, G, and B components, instead of the color terminal-specific one. If your terminal emulator doesn't support the so-called "true colors" feature, then it can't make sense of what Vim is telling it to do and you get a messed-up colorscheme.

Since Terminal.app doesn't support "true colors", enabling `&termguicolors` simply can't work. It couldn't work before the system upgrade and it can't work after.

If you absolutely *need* "true colors", get a terminal emulator that supports the feature, like iTerm.

If you can live without it, don't enable it.